# How to set XCTest to run on device

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I would like to run the `XCTest` on my device, it runs ok on simulator but whenever the target was set to device the test will just show Test Succeeded.

I had set a wildcard profile so it shouldnt be the provisioning issues.

I'm trying to run this **test:**

```
//always fail on simulator
func testCheckLiveLapInstalled()
{
   XCTAssertTrue(UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"livelabs://")!), "Live Lab Not Installed")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on that line to confirm whether or not it is reaching it? And also try clicking the 'run' icon that appears in the gutter beside `testCheckLiveLapInstalled`

Comment: @Michael yea i did. xcode builded and just pop up Test Succeeded.